# Drupal8 modules/custom/folder doesn't exist?

Tags: module, ubuntu-14.04, drupal-8

I have installed drupal 8 on ubuntu. All works well but I cannot create new module using Drupal console cus i cannot locate "Custom" folder to create and install module[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0ZFg.png)

Comment: check manually var/www/html/maryem/modules/custom directories are exist if not then create and make the folder writable mean set permissions like 777 else if path is exits then check permission for folders and set to 777

Comment: you welcome merry if this solve your problem then don't forget to make my comment as answered

Answer (score 0):

you should make the path by yourself first then use it it module builder

Comment: i made the path by myself ..but nothing happened :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check the drupal console documentation https://docs.drupalconsole.com/en/commands/generate-module.html

You need the option --module-path "path" to create a new module in the desired directory. Any valid path is acceptable.
Drupal Console short command.

**drupal gm --module "module_name" --module-path "sites/all/modules/custom" --description "Test" --core "8.x"**